# OOP, Is it good practice to call getter methods of another object inside the Constructor of an object?

Tags: c#, constructor

Im trying to create a `StandardMidiFile` Object, 
It will contain a `HeaderChunk` Object 
and a `TrackChunk` object.

The `TrackChunk` Object will contain `MidiEvent` objects.

So when I create this `StandardMidiFile` Object, 
I want it's constructor to construct & contain the other objects.

But, when the `TrackChunk`  Object is created it first needs to call a getter method in a GUI-UserControl Class that will determine the total Length of the all MidiEvents in bytes.
And that value will then be used in constructing the `TrackChunk`.

Is it good OOP practice to call a method inside a constructor?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you ask this question..?!

Comment: Thanks to those who voted down my question, which was genuine concerning good practice. 

I have lost some early privelages because of this. 
I don't understand why you would do this to a fellow programmer, that is just a student asking a question on a forum for... asking questions.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either. It's a legitimate question. If you downvote, it should be mandatory to explain why, in the spirit of improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is pass in the track length as a constructor parameter.

```
class StandardMidiFile
{
    HeaderChunk header;
    TrackChunk track;

    public StandardMidiFile()
    {
        var trackLength = // call GUI-UserControl class to get value
        header = new HeaderChunk();
        track = new TrackChunk(trackLength);
    }
}

class HeaderChunk
{
    // blah blah blah
}

class TrackChunk
{
    // blah blah blah

    public TrackChunk(var trackLength)
    {
        // Do stuff here.
    }
}
```

Of course, it really depends on the rest of your design. If TrackChunk is intended to be only an object used in StandardMidiFile, then this makes more sense to me. Either way is "correct", I believe.

Answer (score 2):

It's neither good nor bad in general.  There are specific situations in which it could be either good or bad.  Finding 'bad' ones would be a bit harder though; there's nothing inherently wrong with the idea.

Comment: And what problems do you see in that example?  What about it makes you question whether or not it's a good idea?

Comment: Im still learning and I've never seen constructors that call methods

Comment: It's quite common for a constructor to call methods; there is nothing inherently wrong with that, as I said above.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to initialize your object depending on another one, this seems like the right thing to do. If, for example, you have a 'Settings' class, it would even make sense for a lot of new instances to try and access its inner fields, to know how to initialize themselves.
In general, this is neither always good nor always bad; as usually in programming, it depends on the specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should. Perhaps expand on the question, provide an example and that'll help with your answers.

Comment: This should go into the comments section instead :)